# Spring downloading upgraded version automatically

Tags: java, spring, maven, pom.xml, parent-pom

In my application I am using `grovvy` dependency for using a class called `GrovvyClassLoader`. Earlier I was using spring version `2.2.11.RELEASE` and my `grovvy` was on `2.5.13`. Since I have upgraded to spring `2.6.6`, it tends to download `grovvy` version `3.0.10` automatically.

I have tried to use `<grovvy.version>` tag inside `<properties>` tag in pom file to prevent spring from downloading `grovvy` automatically but even that is not helpful. Surprising is the fact that even `grovvy` dependency in my pom is set to version `2.5.13`.

This my pom(parent pom),

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.6</version>
    <relativePath/>
  </parent>

 <properties>
   .
   .
   .
<groovy.version>2.5.13</groovy.version>
  </properties>
```

This is a child pom to the above pom where I am actually setting dependency for `grovvy`,

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
      <artifactId>groovy</artifactId>
      <version>2.5.13</version>
    </dependency>
```

Can anybody tell me why is spring overriding my version and how can stop it.

Comment: there is a typo in your parent pom: `grovvy.version` - should be `groovy.version`

Comment: Ohh sorry, u can ignore that btw.

Comment: Just tested your code (with and without the optional "depedency.version 2.5.1.3") and it works. I'm afraid you'll have to show us more code than that.